# Angular UI mask is not working

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I would like to have multiple masking for the input element. it should allow either 5 or 9 digits like the below,

99-999

999-999-999

but ui-mask allows only one mask at a time. Is there any way to do both at the same time?

Here the sample link for UI mask 
http://codepen.io/josephleehunsaker/pen/Fhnsg`

**UI Mask**

```
<input type="text" ui-mask="999-999-999" ng-model="greeting" />
```

Comment: I believe it is not possible. You need a Regex and ui-mask does not seems to allow that. You might need to use something like this http://alphagit.github.io/ng-pattern-restrict/